# is there any short method to obtain value of array in php

Tags: php, arrays

When I obtain a field 'text' of an array I have to do something like this:

```
$text = isset($tab['text'][0])?$tab['text'][0]:"";
```

is there any function that returns value when element `$tab['text']` exists and `""` when not and of course doesn't produce notice in latter case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = @$tab['text'][0];
//------^
```

Note, `$text` could be `NULL`. To work around this:

```
$text = @$tab['text'][0] . "";
//------^
```

Comment: This will return null instead of the empty string. Error control operator is also ugly thing :)

Answer (score 2):

The [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) `?:` can be used this way in PHP 5.3:

```
return $tab['text'][0] ?: '';
```

Comment: Great - I didn't noticed this change in 5.3 until now :)

Comment: Oops, won't it generate a `E_NOTICE` under certain error_reporting configurations?

Comment: Yes, it will. The example code in the question will, too. That's why I posted it anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$search_array = array('first' => 1, 'second' => 4);
if (array_key_exists('first', $search_array)) {
    echo "The 'first' element is in the array";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no shorter way to do it in PHP. I'm assuming you're looking for something like the javascripts' `var foo = bar || false`, but PHP only has the ternary operator, like in your example.